# How to proceed to the next cycle?

Tags: python, pyrogram

This code sends a message to the Telegram Supergroup if a new member has joined. When an error occurs when sending a message, I want to change my account to continue. It is possible to go to the next "item".
How do I go to the next account in a loop when I receive an error?

```
from pyrogram import Client, Filters

list_account = ['001', '002']

for item in list_account:
    app = Client(item)
    @app.on_message(Filters.chat("public_link_chat") & Filters.new_chat_members)
    def welcome(client, message):
        try:
            client.send_message(
                message.chat.id, 'Test',
                reply_to_message_id=message.message_id,
                disable_web_page_preview=True
            )
        except Exception as e:
            print(e)
            # How do I go to the next account in a loop when I receive an error?

    app.start()
    app.join_chat("public_link_chat")
    app.idle()
```

Function "continue" does not work in this case.

Description of function here: https://docs.pyrogram.ml/resources/UpdateHandling

Comment: When you say "get something like this", what do you mean? What's stopping you from doing so? (Yes, you're called on an event-driven basis, but how does that impede you?)

Comment: I don't see where you're stuck.  `return` is how you pass a value back from a function.  If you want the `welcome` value, then use `return` and keep it in a variable in the calling program.

Comment: @Prune, `welcome` is called by `pyrogram`, not by the OP's code directly, so the handling of the return value is controlled by that library. Not that that makes the OP's question any clearer, but "just return a value from welcome" doesn't make sense when welcome is a callback invoked by a separate component.

Comment: ...of course, their `welcome` function can call `number_one()` and print the returned value.

Comment: I really don't understand this question.

Comment: Corrected the question. I think it will be so clearer.

Comment: Try adding a `app.stop()` in your exception handler and see if it helps. If your `app.start()` raises an exception then you will need to handle that as well

Comment: @tarun-lalwani Does not work anyway

Comment: Remove the `app.idle()` as well. Also put a  breakpoint to see if your code moves after `app.start()` after the stop

Comment: telegram calls on message your welcome function. So you aren't even called from the for loop, and thats why you cant continue to next iteration.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just add `app.is_idle = False`:

```
from pyrogram import Client, Filters

list_account = ['001', '002']

for item in list_account:
    app = Client(item)
    @app.on_message(Filters.chat("public_link_chat") & Filters.new_chat_members)
    def welcome(client, message):
        try:
            client.send_message(
                message.chat.id, 'Test',
                reply_to_message_id=message.message_id,
                disable_web_page_preview=True
            )
        except Exception as e:
            print(e)
            # How do I go to the next account in a loop when I receive an error?
            app.is_idle = False

    app.start()
    app.join_chat("public_link_chat")
    app.idle()
```

You should definitely check out [these lines](https://github.com/pyrogram/pyrogram/blob/develop/pyrogram/client/client.py#L890-L891) of the idle logic at the pyrogram source code:

```py
while self.is_idle:
    time.sleep(1)
```

If you want an infinite loop, [check out](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.cycle) the `itertools.cycle`, it may be used like:

```py
for item in itertools.cycle(list_account):
    do_something()
```

Comment: Thank you for your help!